# The different custom analyzers for index and search in Elasticsearch giving NULL results for user queries

Tags: elasticsearch, search, kibana, analyzer

In this code I am defining two different custom analyzers for both indexing time and search time, and in mapping field also i have specified the "analyzer" as well as "search_analyzer".

```
PUT /demo
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym_test":{
            "type":"synonym",
            "synonyms_path":"analysis/output.txt"
          },
          "english_stop":{
            "type":"stop",
            "stopwords":"_english_"
        },
          "en_US":{
            "type":"hunspell",
            "language":"en_US"
        }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "synonym_test",
              "english_stop",
              "en_US"
            ],
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          },
          "complete":{
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "english_stop",
              "en_US"
            ],
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
 "mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "Content":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "complete"
      },
    "query":{
      "type":"percolator"
    }
    }
  }
}
```

I checked the above query using analyze api.

```
GET demo/_analyze
{
  "text": "fractured"
  , "analyzer": "autocomplete"
}
```

It is showing the token :

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "fracture",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Also on running :

```
GET demo/_analyze
{
  "text": "fractured"
  , "analyzer": "complete"
}
```

it is showing the token:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "fracture",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a demo as :

```
PUT demo/_doc/1
{
"Content":"fracture foot"
}
```

But when I write a search query as :

```
GET demo/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "Content": {
                "query": "fracture"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or if I write :

```
GET demo/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "Content": {
                "query": "fractured"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For both the queries, I am getting null results.
Please Help me with this issue.
**en_US is Hunspell dictionary stemmer and I also have added synonym filter.**
Please help me.

Comment: Does using Synonym filter during indexing and not using synonym filter during search time creates a problem? if yes then why does it creates a problem using search API?

Comment: Can you provide list of synonyms related to fracture?

Comment: fracture => break, split, rupture, broken

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved , I just changed the synonyms inside synonym file from like "fracture => break, split, rupture, broken" to "fracture,break, split, rupture, broken" and all the words are now being indexed.